# @property gets writeable when attribute is of dict type

Tags: python, dictionary, properties, setter

#### @property defined as `int`

The following code is taken from [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Parrot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._voltage = 100000

    @property
    def voltage(self):
        """Get the current voltage."""
        return self._voltage
```

When I run:

```
parrot = Parrot()
print(parrot.voltage)
parrot.voltage = 100
print(parrot.voltage)
```

I get the following output (as expected, as no *setter* is defined)

```
{0: 100000}
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "prop.py", line 13, in <module>
     parrot.voltage = 100
 AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

#### @property defined as `dict`

However, if I define `self._voltage = {}` the **property becomes writeable**:

```
class Parrot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._voltage = {}
        self._voltage[0] = 100000

    @property
    def voltage(self):
        """Get the current voltage."""
        return self._voltage

parrot = Parrot()
print(parrot.voltage)
parrot.voltage[0] = 100
print(parrot.voltage)
```

The output is then:

```
{0: 100000}
{0: 100}
```

Same behavior in Python 2.7.9 and Python 3.4.3. Why is the property writeable, even if no *setter* is explicitly defined in the code? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137685/using-pythons-property-decorator-on-dicts) it was proposed to subclass `dict` to get this behavior. However, it seems that this not required.

Comment: Because now you're updating the object returned by the getter. A property will only take care of `parrot.voltage = 100` not `parrot.voltage[0] = 100`.

Comment: You are *not setting the property*. You are mutating a mutable object. Same with any other object that can be mutated; list, set, another custom class instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the property. You are manipulating a mutable object.

The assignment is not on the property itself, but on a *subscription*, the `[..]` part addresses a dictionary key. You could assign the property to a new name and still manipulate that dictionary:

```
parrot = Parrot()
parrot_voltage = parrot.voltage
parrot_voltage[0] = 100
```

but you cannot set the property to a new dictionary or a different type of object altogether. This applies to all mutable objects used in a property; lists, sets, instances, etc.